# try catch vs try-with-resources

Tags: java, exception

Why in the `readFile2()` I need to catch the `FileNotFoundException` and later the `IOException` that is thrown by the `close()` method, and in the `try-with-resources(inside readfile1)` Java doesn't ask me to handle the `FileNotFoundException`, what happened?

```
public class TryWithResourcesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static void readFile1() {
        try(Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readFile2() {
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(reader != null)
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you look at the javadocs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html you will see that FileNotFoundException is a subclass of IOException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`. By catching the latter, you're catching the former too. It has nothing to do with try-catch vs. try-with-resources.